# Python 2.7 - Permissions Error when writing a file to a specific Directory from a URL

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting a permission's error when writing multiple files to a specific directory from a url, specifically an SFTP site. Here is an example of what I am trying to run.

```
import pycurl, urllib2, requests, json, pprint, urllib, os
from io import BytesIO

files = []
c = pycurl.Curl()
data = BytesIO()
c.setopt(c.URL, "https://sftp.mmm.com:443/api/v1.1/files/Source_Directory/")
c.setopt(c.USERPWD, "username:password")
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, data)
c.perform()
c.close()
dictionary = json.loads(data.getvalue())


for i in dictionary['files']:
    files.append(i["fileName"])


for x in files:

    c = pycurl.Curl()
    file = open(x, "a+")
    c.setopt(c.URL, "https://sftp.pjm.com:443/api/v1.1/files/Source_directory/"+x)
    c.setopt(c.USERPWD, "username:password")
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, file)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
    file.close()
```

When i use "x" in the file - open (x, "a+") the files write to my python project folder. However if I replace the x with a specific directory like my desktop I get IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "Destination_Directory"

Comment: Looks like it is because you can write the file specifically do the directory you need to create a placeholder file then drop it in. I got it to work by doing file = open("Destination_directory" + x, "a+")

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because what you are doing requires administrator. Simply run your IDE as administrator (by right clicking and clicking run as administrator). If you are running it from command prompt, run command prompt as administrator.